# mapping json columns to pandas dataframe columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the below which takes some JSON input and converts to a Pandas dataframe.

But, because the JSON doesn't have a consistent schema, it's all misaligned. (if a field doesn't exist in one entry, it shifts everything to the left)

Is there any way I can say the below & explicitly define it?

```
df.field1 = json.field1
```

If I can define by their names, I can do it nicely :)

Thanks

```
output = subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True)

# output of subprocess will be bytes, converting to string.
if isinstance(output, bytes):
    output = output.decode()

output = json.loads(output)
df = pd.DataFrame(output['apps']['app'])
df = df.loc[df['startedTime'] > starttime]
df.to_csv('yarn_output.csv')
```

Sample Input JSON

```
{"apps":{"app":[{"id":"application_1589431105417_21534","user":"udsldr","name":"HIVE-61a4ee14-1d26-4c7b-bf0d-1cc2a990557d","queue":"udsldr","state":"FINISHED","finalStatus":"SUCCEEDED","progress":100.0,"trackingUI":"History","trackingUrl":"http://uds-far-mn4.dab.02.net:8088/proxy/application_1589431105417_21534/","diagnostics":"Session stats:submittedDAGs=0, successfulDAGs=0, failedDAGs=0, killedDAGs=0\n","clusterId":1589431105417,"applicationType":"TEZ","applicationTags":"","priority":0,"startedTime":1590294649069,"finishedTime":1590294666011,"elapsedTime":16942,"amContainerLogs":"http://uds-far-dn150.dab.02.net:8042/node/containerlogs/container_e66_1589431105417_21534_01_000001/udsldr","amHostHttpAddress":"uds-far-dn150.dab.02.net:8042","allocatedMB":-1,"allocatedVCores":-1,"runningContainers":-1,"memorySeconds":144531,"vcoreSeconds":17,"queueUsagePercentage":0.0,"clusterUsagePercentage":0.0,"preemptedResourceMB":0,"preemptedResourceVCores":0,"numNonAMContainerPreempted":0,"numAMContainerPreempted":0,"logAggregationStatus":"SUCCEEDED","unmanagedApplication":false,"amNodeLabelExpression":""},{"id":"application_1589431105417_21535","user":"nifildr","name":"HIVE-850812d7-9d22-4be8-a225-7b341f6ea980","queue":"default","state":"FINISHED","finalStatus":"SUCCEEDED","progress":100.0,"trackingUI":"History","trackingUrl":"http://uds-far-mn4.dab.02.net:8088/proxy/application_1589431105417_21535/","diagnostics":"Session stats:submittedDAGs=0, successfulDAGs=1, failedDAGs=0, killedDAGs=0\n","clusterId":1589431105417,"applicationType":"TEZ","applicationTags":"","priority":0,"startedTime":1590294664397,"finishedTime":1590294801090,"elapsedTime":136693,"amContainerLogs":"http://uds-far-dn129.dab.02.net:8042/node/containerlogs/container_e66_1589431105417_21535_01_000001/nifildr","amHostHttpAddress":"uds-far-dn129.dab.02.net:8042","allocatedMB":-1,"allocatedVCores":-1,"runningContainers":-1,"memorySeconds":18279340,"vcoreSeconds":4248,"queueUsagePercentage":0.0,"clusterUsagePercentage":0.0,"preemptedResourceMB":0,"preemptedResourceVCores":0,"numNonAMContainerPreempted":0,"numAMContainerPreempted":0,"logAggregationStatus":"TIME_OUT","unmanagedApplication":false,"amNodeLabelExpression":""},{"id":"application_1589431105417_21532","user":"udsldr","name":"HIVE-73e0c359-32a5-4334-89da-4a8ae2bb1037","queue":"udsldr","state":"FINISHED","finalStatus":"SUCCEEDED","progress":100.0,"trackingUI":"History","trackingUrl":"http://uds-far-mn4.dab.02.net:8088/proxy/application_1589431105417_21532/","diagnostics":"Session stats:submittedDAGs=0, successfulDAGs=0, failedDAGs=0, killedDAGs=0\n","clusterId":1589431105417,"applicationType":"TEZ","applicationTags":"","priority":0,"startedTime":1590294622244,"finishedTime":1590294643808,"elapsedTime":21564,"amContainerLogs":"http://uds-far-dn35.dab.02.net:8042/node/containerlogs/container_e66_1589431105417_21532_01_000001/udsldr","amHostHttpAddress":"uds-far-dn35.dab.02.net:8042","allocatedMB":-1,"allocatedVCores":-1,"runningContainers":-1,"memorySeconds":182247,"vcoreSeconds":22,"queueUsagePercentage":0.0,"clusterUsagePercentage":0.0,"preemptedResourceMB":0,"preemptedResourceVCores":0,"numNonAMContainerPreempted":0,"numAMContainerPreempted":0,"logAggregationStatus":"SUCCEEDED","unmanagedApplication":false,"amNodeLabelExpression":""},{"id":"application_1589431105417_21533","user":"udssupport","name":"tcs.uds.webstats","queue":"udssystem","state":"FINISHED","finalStatus":"SUCCEEDED","progress":100.0,"trackingUI":"History","trackingUrl":"http://uds-far-mn4.dab.02.net:8088/proxy/application_1589431105417_21533/","diagnostics":"","clusterId":1589431105417,"applicationType":"SPARK","applicationTags":"","priority":0,"startedTime":1590294631138,"finishedTime":1590295670552,"elapsedTime":1039414,"amContainerLogs":"http://uds-far-dn148.dab.02.net:8042/node/containerlogs/container_e66_1589431105417_21533_01_000001/udssupport","amHostHttpAddress":"uds-far-dn148.dab.02.net:8042","allocatedMB":-1,"allocatedVCores":-1,"runningContainers":-1,"memorySeconds":4762538052,"vcoreSeconds":775756,"queueUsagePercentage":0.0,"clusterUsagePercentage":0.0,"preemptedResourceMB":0,"preemptedResourceVCores":0,"numNonAMContainerPreempted":0,"numAMContainerPreempted":0,"logAggregationStatus":"TIME_OUT","unmanagedApplication":false,"amNodeLabelExpression":""},{"id":"application_1589431105417_21530","user":"nifildr","name":"HIVE-e9a64e12-11f0-4ba8-b069-3be0ce561137","queue":"default","state":"FINISHED","finalStatus":"SUCCEEDED","progress":100.0,"trackingUI":"History","trackingUrl":"http://uds-far-mn4.dab.02.net:8088/proxy/application_1589431105417_21530/","diagnostics":"Session stats:submittedDAGs=0, successfulDAGs=3, failedDAGs=0, killedDAGs=0\n","clusterId":1589431105417,"applicationType":"TEZ","applicationTags":"","priority":0,"startedTime":1590294606965,"finishedTime":1590295033193,"elapsedTime":426228,"amContainerLogs":"http://uds-far-dn75.dab.02.net:8042/node/containerlogs/container_e66_1589431105417_21530_01_000001/nifildr","amHostHttpAddress":"uds-far-dn75.dab.02.net:8042","allocatedMB":-1,"allocatedVCores":-1,"runningContainers":-1,"memorySeconds":114397555,"vcoreSeconds":27175,"queueUsagePercentage":0.0,"clusterUsagePercentage":0.0,"preemptedResourceMB":0,"preemptedResourceVCores":0,"numNonAMContainerPreempted":0,"numAMContainerPreempted":0,"logAggregationStatus":"TIME_OUT","unmanagedApplication":false,"amNodeLabelExpression":""},{"id":"application_1589431105417_21531","user":"nifi","name":"HIVE-a063ddd1-5bf8-47b4-8ce3-8497c93b79a5","queue":"default","state":"FINISHED","finalStatus":"SUCCEEDED","progress":100.0,"trackingUI":"History","trackingUrl":"http://uds-far-mn4.dab.02.net:8088/proxy/application_1589431105417_21531/","diagnostics":"Session stats:submittedDAGs=0, successfulDAGs=0, failedDAGs=0, killedDAGs=0\n","clusterId":1589431105417,"applicationType":"TEZ","applicationTags":"","priority":0,"startedTime":1590294613578,"finishedTime":1590294655173,"elapsedTime":41595,"amContainerLogs":"http://uds-far-dn56.dab.02.net:8042/node/containerlogs/container_e66_1589431105417_21531_01_000001/nifi","amHostHttpAddress":"uds-far-dn56.dab.02.net:8042","allocatedMB":-1,"allocatedVCores":-1,"runningContainers":-1,"memorySeconds":345792,"vcoreSeconds":42,"queueUsagePercentage":0.0,"clusterUsagePercentage":0.0,"preemptedResourceMB":0,"preemptedResourceVCores":0,"numNonAMContainerPreempted":0,"numAMContainerPreempted":0,"logAggregationStatus":"SUCCEEDED","unmanagedApplication":false,"amNodeLabelExpression":""},{"id":"application_1589431105417_21528","user":"udsldr","name":"com.cardinality.LocationDB","queue":"udsldr","state":"FINISHED","finalStatus":"SUCCEEDED","progress":100.0,"trackingUI":"History","trackingUrl":"http://uds-far-mn4.dab.02.net:8088/proxy/application_1589431105417_21528/","diagnostics":"","clusterId":1589431105417,"applicationType":"SPARK","applicationTags":"5ec9f8480000f1697e683969","priority":0,"startedTime":1590294605875,"finishedTime":1590294782281,"elapsedTime":176406,"amContainerLogs":"http://uds-far-dn167.dab.02.net:8042/node/containerlogs/container_e66_1589431105417_21528_01_000001/udsldr","amHostHttpAddress":"uds-far-dn167.dab.02.net:8042","allocatedMB":-1,"allocatedVCores":-1,"runningContainers":-1,"memorySeconds":43389139,"vcoreSeconds":5239,"queueUsagePercentage":0.0,"clusterUsagePercentage":0.0,"preemptedResourceMB":0,"preemptedResourceVCores":0,"numNonAMContainerPreempted":0,"numAMContainerPreempted":0,"logAggregationStatus":"TIME_OUT","unmanagedApplication":false,"amNodeLabelExpression":""},{"id":"application_1589431105417_21529","user":"keenek1","name":"Clean DPI Report","queue":"default","state":"FINISHED","finalStatus":"SUCCEEDED","progress":100.0,"trackingUI":"History","trackingUrl":"http://uds-far-mn4.dab.02.net:8088/proxy/application_1589431105417_21529/","diagnostics":"","clusterId":1589431105417,"applicationType":"SPARK","applicationTags":"","priority":0,"startedTime":1590294607111,"finishedTime":1590295032105,"elapsedTime":424994,"amContainerLogs":"http://uds-far-dn62.dab.02.net:8042/node/containerlogs/container_e66_1589431105417_21529_01_000001/keenek1","amHostHttpAddress":"uds-far-dn62.dab.02.net:8042","allocatedMB":-1,"allocatedVCores":-1,"runningContainers":-1,"memorySeconds":2114077299,"vcoreSeconds":344079,"queueUsagePercentage":0.0,"clusterUsagePercentage":0.0,"preemptedResourceMB":0,"preemptedResourceVCores":0,"numNonAMContainerPreempted":0,"numAMContainerPreempted":0,"logAggregationStatus":"TIME_OUT","unmanagedApplication":false,"amNodeLabelExpression":""},{"id":"application_1589431105417_21542","user":"murugaa1","name":"HIVE-a1a5aadb-254c-4289-ad22-e9c7ce5e9814","queue":"default","state":"FINISHED","finalStatus":"SUCCEEDED","progress":100.0,"trackingUI":"History","trackingUrl":"http://uds-far-mn4.dab.02.net:8088/proxy/application_1589431105417_21542/","diagnostics":"Session stats:submittedDAGs=0, successfulDAGs=1, failedDAGs=0, killedDAGs=0\n","clusterId":1589431105417,"applicationType":"TEZ","applicationTags":"","priority":0,"startedTime":1590295275713,"finishedTime":1590295297948,"elapsedTime":22235,"amContainerLogs":"http://uds-far-dn46.dab.02.net:8042/node/containerlogs/container_e66_1589431105417_21542_01_000001/murugaa1","amHostHttpAddress":"uds-far-dn46.dab.02.net:8042","allocatedMB":-1,"allocatedVCores":-1,"runningContainers":-1,"memorySeconds":999465,"vcoreSeconds":217,"queueUsagePercentage":0.0,"clusterUsagePercentage":0.0,"preemptedResourceMB":0,"preemptedResourceVCores":0,"numNonAMContainerPreempted":0,"numAMContainerPreempted":0,"logAggregationStatus":"SUCCEEDED","unmanagedApplication":false,"amNodeLabelExpression":""},{"id":"application_1589431105417_21543","user":"murugaa1","name":"HIVE-cdc8a5da-f880-4f8e-9baf-b306095b9efb","queue":"default","state":"FINISHED","finalStatus":"SUCCEEDED","progress":100.0,"trackingUI":"History","trackingUrl":"http://uds-far-mn4.dab.02.net:8088/proxy/application_1589431105417_21543/","diagnostics":"Session stats:submittedDAGs=0, successfulDAGs=1, failedDAGs=0, killedDAGs=0\n","clusterId":1589431105417,"applicationType":"TEZ","applicationTags":"","priority":0,"startedTime":1590295277611,"finishedTime":1590295301515,"elapsedTime":23904,"amContainerLogs":"http://uds-far-dn41.dab.02.net:8042/node/containerlogs/container_e66_1589431105417_21543_01_000001/murugaa1","amHostHttpAddress":"uds-far-dn41.dab.02.net:8042","allocatedMB":-1,"allocatedVCores":-1,"runningContainers":-1,"memorySeconds":1077860,"vcoreSeconds":228,"queueUsagePercentage":0.0,"clusterUsagePercentage":0.0,"preemptedResourceMB":0,"preemptedResourceVCores":0,"numNonAMContainerPreempted":0,"numAMContainerPreempted":0,"logAggregationStatus":"SUCCEEDED","unmanagedApplication":false,"amNodeLabelExpression":""}]}}
```

CSV output:

```
allocatedMB|applicationType|diagnostics|finalStatus|finishedTime|memorySeconds|queue|startedTime|user|vcoreSeconds
-1|TEZ|"Session stats:submittedDAGs=0, successfulDAGs=0, failedDAGs=0, killedDAGs=0
"|SUCCEEDED|1590294666011|144531|udsldr|1590294649069|udsldr|17
-1|TEZ|"Session stats:submittedDAGs=0, successfulDAGs=1, failedDAGs=0, killedDAGs=0
"|SUCCEEDED|1590294801090|18279340|default|1590294664397|nifildr|4248
-1|TEZ|"Session stats:submittedDAGs=0, successfulDAGs=0, failedDAGs=0, killedDAGs=0
```

Comment: Can you please provide a sample of `output` and expected outcome?

Comment: Thanks! I have updated that. The expected outcome is just a table, with all the fields from the JSON. If the field is not populated for one of the entries, it can just be empty

Comment: Do you just want to rename the columns in the final df?

Comment: if the JSON entry does not contain let's say FinalStatus field, then all the fields afterwards are currently misaligned. I need them to still be in the correct column and not be affected by the flexible json schema

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by misaligned? If finalStatus does not exist, it will be NaN. Not sure I understand your question

Comment: It should be NaN but it isn't - it just shifts all the other columns left & the values do not align with their field heading

Comment: I suppose I would quite like to manually define it. Like json[id] --> df[id] to make sure there is no possibility for error

Comment: Can you print your df and show the output? I don't know why you're not getting NaN there. I used your code and got a NaN if finalStatus wasn't present

Comment: The dataframe is correct, and I assume that the csv is too. But if you use Excel to look at a csv file, anything can happen... More seriously, Excel does know about csv, but it expects the separator to follow the locale (`;` in many West European countries) when by default Python uses a comma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a different delimiter when converting to csv, I think the misalignment is happening because of commas:

```
df.to_csv('123.csv', sep='|', index=['id'])
```

Comment: Thanks for this - the dataframe is 100% correct but the .to_csv is messing it up. On the output, I can see the first fields are misaligned which casues a knock on effect.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I have just added that above. You can see in application type, where there is no allocated MB we get succeeded rather than TEZ, Spark or Empty.

Comment: Ahh ignore me, I see it wraps around now :)

Comment: When I dump it into a DB table, it is all misaligned, so it looks like it's doing a new line in the CSV and thats messing up the DB table. Because the second line of the CSV shows as the second row of the DB table, when it shouldbe a continuation of the first

Comment: Ok just use `read_csv()` on that generated csv to ensure it is creating a df correctly

Comment: Thanks for all the help, it is. I still have NO idea why it's not coming through properly in the DB table, but that sounds like a problem for tomorrow :)

Comment: I know why its happening, there's a \n there  - killedDAGs=0\n. This line is the culprit:
`"diagnostics": "Session stats:submittedDAGs=0, successfulDAGs=0, failedDAGs=0, killedDAGs=0\n",` in the JSON and the CSV

Comment: you're awesome, thanks so much for the help! So i could just do: df = df.replace(r'\\n',' ', regex=True)